# Find items where DynamoDB attribute is not set *or* greater than x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am attempting to scan a DynamoDB table from Lambda (Node.js) to check if a token has expired. I would like to filter the data to exclude items where `expiration_time` is set and is less than the current time. I currently get a false positive for units where no `expiration_time` is set.

How can I check for an expired timestamp *or* no `expiration_time` attribute set at all?

```js
dynamodb.scan({
    "TableName": "fm_tokens",
    "AttributesToGet": ["user_id"],
    "ScanFilter": {
        "token": {
            "AttributeValueList": [{"S": tkn.toString()}],
            "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"
        },
        "token_time": {
            "AttributeValueList": [{"N": expiration.toString()}],
            "ComparisonOperator": "GE"
        },
        "expiration_time": {
            "AttributeValueList": [{"N": unix_timestamp.toString()}],
            "ComparisonOperator": "GE",
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the best way to perform an "OR" operation is to use the new, string-based filtering commands. `AttributesToGet` is replaced by `ProjectionExpression`, and `ScanFilter` is replaced by `FilterExpression`.

Note that with the new commands you will not be able to use [reserved words](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) and must work around any reserved words by defining those keys with `ExpressionAttributeNames` and any values with `ExpressionAttributeValues`.

```js
dynamodb.scan({
  // Define table to scan
    "TableName": "fm_tokens",
  // Only return selected values (optional)
    "ProjectionExpression": "user_id",
  // Write your expression, similar to SQL syntax
    "FilterExpression": 
        "#token = :tkn AND "+
        "token_time >= :expiration AND "+
        "(attribute_not_exists(expiration_time) OR expiration_time >= :timestamp)",
  // Use this to avoid reserved words by defining variables with the name instead
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#token": "token"
    },
  // Same as with names, but for values - must include value type (S, N, etc.)
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":tkn": {"S": tkn},
        ":expiration": {"N": expiration.toString()},
        ":timestamp": {"N": unix_timestamp.toString()}
    }
}
```